# Setup BOSH so that it allows for users to login without passwords for a long period of time?

Tags: session, authentication, xmpp

I'm just wondering how one could set this up without the BOSH dying. I have the sid, rid, and everything but I was wondering how long i could automatically log people on for the time of lets say a cookie and how is this achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer depends on how long it takes for your BOSH session to timeout. It's usually 60 seconds until it throws away the session.

Just a note- you probably do *not* want to automatically log in a user, since the proper XMPP flow is not done. Here's a typical flow:

-> Login and establish a BOSH session.

-> Send Presence
---> Server sends a <presence/> packet to all entities in your roster, notifying them that you are available.
---> Server sends a presence probe to all of the entities in your roster's server, getting their current availability.
<- Presence packets come raining down on your session.

-> Request roster items
<- Server sends you a list of items in your roster.

With the approach of using the same session, you skip all of this initialization, which I assume is important to your application, as you will **not** get presence of any entities until they change their presence. Sending another <presence/> stanza will **not** send you the current presence of everyone in your roster. So... if that isn't important to you, go ahead and do it. I'm just providing some useful information before you go and implement the thing and find out that there are caveats to your solution.

What worked for us was to use localStorage, and automatically log them in via a "Save my password" button. That makes it simpler and less work. Also, it can be confusing when a user reloads the page and they get logged back in automatically, versus a user closing the page and coming back in 5 minutes to be greeted by the login page. It's just plain confusing.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following as per your need and convenience:

1. Auto detect about user login status via cookies. Do an http-pre-bind and issue new rid/sid to the user. This will generally be transparent to user on your page.
2. Instead of issuing new "sid" on every page refresh/reload which can be quite expensive under high traffic, you can pool the underlying xmpp tcp streams. Next time when a user need sid/rid to start again, these can be fetched from the connection manager pooling the sessions.